# How to create a polyline feature from a point layer

Tags: arcpy, point, polyline-creation

I would like to create a route line based on a point layer. The existing tool does not meet the customer requirement. But using the code snippet below, the start point and end point are always the same. Does it means they point to the same instance? Please help. Thanks.

```
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(pntLyr, whereStr, "", "", "STOPA A") 
start=True
for row in rows: 

    if (start==True):
        start_feat=row
        start=False
    else:
        end_feat=row
        # create the line based on the start_feat.shape and end_feat.shape
        # Before I reassign the start_feat, start_feat and end_feat already point to the same feature now at this point
        start_feat=row
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `else` block you're defining both `start_feat` and `end_feat` to be the exact same thing. Also, you want to grab `row.Shape`, not the entire row object.

Comment: The question is before I reassign the start_feat=row, it already points to the same row as the end_feat does. Or in other way, even I remove the start_feat=row in the else block, the start_feat still changes in the iterate instead it is supposed to point to the first feature

Comment: It's still slightly confusing what you are trying to do. Are you converting all the points to a single polyline?

Comment: The where_clause in the search cursor defines the points on a route. The field STOPA defines the sequence of the points. My problem is that the previous row (the start_feat) and the current row (the end_feat) are the same all the time even before I reassign the start_feat.